# Launchbar + panel overlaps when showing a dialog box in fullscreen

Tags: unity, application-development, fullscreen

I'm developing a program for 12.04 that will run on full-screen, so I would like to have full control of what appears on the screen.

However, when I show another window (possibly a dialog/message box), the Unity Panel and Launcher appears on the top and left side of the screen. I've experienced this behavior with other applications (Firefox, Gnubg) as well when in full-screen mode.

I tried to play with the settings, now my dialog box is hidden from the the taskbar, set to float on it's parent, which is my full screen window. The problem still exists.

Is there a way to prevent these panels from showing up, when the new window isn't shown in taskbar, or it's parent is a full-screen window? Or do I need to completely disable them?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Ubuntu that I've noticed.

It could possibly be related to this:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/748539

Comment: The linked bug only affects dual-screen setups so not relevant for this problem in single-screen. This problem is also in armbian (embedded Linux for Orange Pi mini-PCs) so It suggests it may be in either XFCE or Xorg